# LVN_ITEMCHANGING - Distinguish user input

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm handling the `LVN_ITEMCHANGING` message, but it gets signaled every time the check state is changed.

I need a way to distinguish between the user changing the check state, and me calling `ListView_SetCheckState`

Is there any easy way to do this? A different message I don't know about maybe? Or does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a function that sets some flag, thunks through to `ListView_SetCheckState`, and then unsets the flag?

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't think so. And I'm not using MFC.

Comment: The `NMLISTVIEW` structure has a `ptAction` member of type `POINT`. I would imagine that this struct would be undefined if the user did not click the checkbox. Just a thought.

Comment: Does undefined guaranty it will be `NULL`?

Comment: @Josh: Good question. My intuition is telling me yes, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: It's not a pointer.  It doesn't make sense for it to be `NULL`.  Undefined values could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView_SetCheckState **sends** the LVM_SETITEMSTATE message. LVN_ITEMCHANGING message is also **sent** to the control's parent window. This means, the function is synchronous, and LVN_ITEMCHANGING handler is executed before ListView_SetCheckState call returns. This allows to use simple boolean flag, like:

```
bChangedByProgram = TRUE;
ListView_SetCheckState(...);
bChangedByProgram = FALSE;
```

In LVN_ITEMCHANGING handler:

```
if ( ! bChangedByProgram )
{
    // item state is changed by user
}
```